# How to change date format for bibtex chem-acs style?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I am using `biblatex` with the `chem-acs` style, but when citing `@online` `urldate`, it is printing the date as "(accessed 02/08/2019)", yet my professor specifically wants the date for such citations to be in the form of "(accessed Feb 08, 2019)". How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option that controls the formatting of the URL access date is called `urldate`. You probably want `urldate=comp`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=chem-acs, backend=biber, urldate=comp]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,markey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Markey, N. Tame the BeaST, The B to X of BibTeX version 1.3, http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf (accessed Oct. 1, 2006).]