# Change incollection Style for chem-acs style?

Tags: biblatex-chem

I'm using `style=chem-acs` and keep getting the following output:

> Ahmed, T. In *Reservoir Engineering Handbook (Fifth Edition)*, Ahmed, T., Ed., Fifth Edition; Gulf Professional Publishing: 2019, pp 29–121

Yet, I'm wanting it to look like the citation for the *Journal of Physical Chemistry C*:

> Ahmed, T. Chapter 2 - Reservoir-Fluid Properties In *Reservoir Engineering Handbook (Fifth Edition)*; Ahmed, T., Ed.; Gulf Professional Publishing: 2019; pp 29-121.

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[style = chem-acs, articletitle=true, backend=biber, dateabbrev=false, language=english, urldate=comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Refer.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{Refer.bib}
@incollection{TXTBK,
title = "Chapter 2 - Reservoir-Fluid Properties",
editor = "Tarek Ahmed",
booktitle = "Reservoir Engineering Handbook (Fifth Edition)",
publisher = "Gulf Professional Publishing",
edition = "Fifth Edition",
pages = "29 - 121",
year = "2019",
isbn = "978-0-12-813649-2",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-813649-2.00002-5",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128136492000025",
author = "Tarek Ahmed"
}
\end{filecontents*}

Lorem Ipsum\autocite{TXTBK}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not that your question is unclear without a code example, but you would make it much easier for people to get started helping you if you could share a short example document (including a `.bib` entry for the reference in question) that shows what you have so far bibliography/citation wise (that's often called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, my answer to your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531016/35864 also contains something I would call an MWE). That way people have something to play round with and don't have to come up with everything themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for that. With

```
chaptertitle=true,
```

`chem-acs` shows the titles of `@inbook` and `@incollection` entries. The option is analogous to `articletitle` for `@article`s, which you already use.

In the MWE below I have slightly reworked your example entry. There is no need to add the edition in the `booktitle` field, since it is already in `edition`. With `biblatex` it is usually advised to give just the bare integer in the `edition` field. It is also uncommon to add "Chapter 2" to the `title` of a chapter, instead you can give the chapter number in the `chapter` field (if you want to show it at all, often people just give the page ranges). The `doi` field should contain only the DOI, not the `https://doi.org/` part of the DOI. Finally it appears to me that the entry is actually an `@inbook` and not an `@incollection`, since the book appears to be a monograph that was authored in its entirety by Tarek Ahmed.

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs, 
  articletitle=true, chaptertitle=true,
  dateabbrev=false, urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{TXTBK,
  author    = {Tarek Ahmed},
  title     = {Reservoir-Fluid Properties},
  booktitle = {Reservoir Engineering Handbook},
  edition   = {5},
  publisher = {Gulf Professional Publishing},
  chapter   = {2},
  pages     = {29-121},
  year      = {2019},
  isbn      = {978-0-12-813649-2},
  doi       = {10.1016/B978-0-12-813649-2.00002-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum\autocite{TXTBK}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ahmed, T., Reservoir-Fluid Properties In Reservoir Engineering Handbook, 5th ed.; Gulf Professional Publishing: 2019; Chapter 2, pp 29–121.]